# Fragment comes alive after stop

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm working on an Android application which pretty much works like this:
There are two activities.
Activity A leads to activity B.
While pressing back from activity B, the user goes back to Activity A.
I have listeners listening to internet connectivity on a fragment of Activity B.
If I press back button from activity B after staying in B for a considerable amount of time, the app crashes immediately after going to the activity A.
 
On seeing the error logs, I verified that the activity B is paused, Activity A is resumed and that the Fragment in activity B is stopped. But I could also see that the internet listeners in fragment in activity B are still alive even after coming back to activity A, and so it receives the ping response and the fragment seems to be coming alive.
here is the exception message I got:

> *main Thread[main,5, main] Disallowed call from unknown notification listener: "android.service.notification.INotificationListener$Stub$Proxy@ecbe517java.lang.SecurityException: Disallowed call from unknown notification listener: android.service.notification.INotificationListener$Stub$Proxy@ecbe517"*

In the `onStop()` method of my fragment, i have done something like this:

```
myContext.unregisterReceiver(myReceiver) . 

myWifiScanner.pause()

myHandler.quitSafely()
```

I figured out that this is the problem. How can I fix it?
I tried removing all callbacks from all handlers involved in the fragment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to post some of the code you have. Imagine if you can’t figure it out while having the code in front of you, how can we [the community] find a solution to your problem without absolutely no visualization of it. It’s like I’m posting to “cars.stackexchange” saying: I have a car that does this and that but when I close the door I can see the lights on, what is the fix? I tried leaving the windows open but nothing works… any ideas? I hope this helps you better structure the question and ultimately find the answer(s) that you’re looking for.

Comment: its  not the fragmnet it actually is your listener set listener to null in onStop and before invoking listener callbacks (listener.method()) check for null refrence

Comment: Important things: Don’t paste entire chunks of code without consideration, nobody wants to read a wall of boilerplate code. Show us how you add the fragment, show us how you set those listeners and how you destroy them, show us if you have overridden any Activity methods (or fragment) and what are you doing in them that may be relevant to your problem. Show us how you check for internet connectivity in Fragment B, etc.

Comment: actually you must register listener in onAttach and unregister that listenr by setting it to null in onDetach  otherwise its a memory leak. which ends up such crashes and memory hungry aplplication

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your activity life cycle.
Make sure you are pausing or destroying your activities when jumping from one to the next.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html